# rails + paperclip saving images and doc/pdf/txt file as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

My model can save images and also doc files,

If user save the images then it should be save in three sizes like small/big...
If user save doc then It should be save as normal document

Anybody can help me....

Answer (score 1):

You can write `proc` in the styles definition, so you at process time define styles. If there no styles the original file saved only, without processing. See more [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) at Dynamic Configuration section.